# After linux distro upgrade, Moin under WSGI throws 500 errors

Tags: linux, debian, apache-http-server, mod-wsgi, moinmoin

I have a [MoinMoin](http://moinmo.in/) instance installed at `/opt/mydebianwiki`; the wiki runs under [wsgi] / [apache2].  I recently upgraded from Debian Linux 6 (squeeze) to Debian 7 (wheezy); before the upgrade, my [MoinMoin](http://moinmo.in/) instance worked well.

However, after the upgrade to wheezy, I started getting http 500 errors when I tried to access the site.

Googling lead me to this [moin-users thread](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.web.wiki.moin.general/8617), which said that I could just run `su -c "moin --config-dir=/opt/mydebianwiki maint cleancache" www-data` to fix the problem; however, that was equally unsuccessful (see errors at the bottom of the question).

How can I resolve this problem?

---

```
root@tsunami:/opt/mydebianwiki# su -c "moin --config-dir=/opt/mydebianwiki maint cleancache" www-data
2014-03-01 04:14:46,749 WARNING MoinMoin.log:139 using logging configuration read from built-in fallback in MoinMoin.log module!
2014-03-01 04:14:46,887 INFO MoinMoin.config.multiconfig:93 using farm config: /etc/moin/farmconfig.pyc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/moin", line 5, in <module>
    run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MoinMoin/script/moin.py", line 15, in run
    MoinScript().run(showtime=0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MoinMoin/script/__init__.py", line 138, in run
    self.mainloop()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MoinMoin/script/__init__.py", line 261, in mainloop
    plugin_class(args[2:], self.options).run() # all starts again there
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MoinMoin/script/__init__.py", line 138, in run
    self.mainloop()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MoinMoin/script/maint/cleancache.py", line 39, in mainloop
    self.init_request()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MoinMoin/script/__init__.py", line 185, in init_request
    self.request = ScriptContext(url, self.options.page)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MoinMoin/web/contexts.py", line 439, in __init__
    wsgiapp.init(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MoinMoin/wsgiapp.py", line 51, in init
    context.lang = setup_i18n_preauth(context)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MoinMoin/wsgiapp.py", line 233, in setup_i18n_preauth
    i18n.i18n_init(context)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MoinMoin/i18n/__init__.py", line 72, in i18n_init
    meta_cache = caching.CacheEntry(request, 'i18n', 'meta', scope='wiki', use_pickle=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MoinMoin/caching.py", line 71, in __init__
    self.arena_dir = get_arena_dir(request, arena, scope)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MoinMoin/caching.py", line 32, in get_arena_dir
    return os.path.join(request.cfg.cache_dir, request.cfg.siteid, arena)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MoinMoin/web/contexts.py", line 56, in get
    res = obj.environ.setdefault(self.name, factory(obj))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MoinMoin/web/contexts.py", line 128, in cfg
    cfg = multiconfig.getConfig(self.request.url)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MoinMoin/config/multiconfig.py", line 193, in getConfig
    cfg = _makeConfig(cfgName)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MoinMoin/config/multiconfig.py", line 125, in _makeConfig
    cfg = configClass(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MoinMoin/config/multiconfig.py", line 277, in __init__
    self._check_directories()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MoinMoin/config/multiconfig.py", line 604, in _check_directories
    raise error.ConfigurationError(msg)
MoinMoin.error.ConfigurationError:
data_dir "/org/mywiki/data" does not exist, or has incorrect ownership or
permissions.

Make sure the directory and the subdirectory "pages" are owned by the web
server and are readable, writable and executable by the web server user
and group.

It is recommended to use absolute paths and not relative paths. Check
also the spelling of the directory name.

root@tsunami:/opt/mydebianwiki#
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that my local moin configuration at `/opt/mydebianwiki/wikiconfig.py` was not found, even though I specified that directory in my `moin ... maint cleancache` command.   It seems that debian's default directory (`/etc/moin`) was taking precedence when I ran `su -c "moin --config-dir=/opt/mydebianwiki maint cleancache" www-data`.

My solution, was to temporarily rename `/etc/moin` and run the command.  This fixed the problem:

```
root@tsunami:/opt/mydebianwiki# mv /etc/moin/ /etc/antimoin

root@tsunami:/opt/mydebianwiki# su -c "moin --config-dir=/opt/mydebianwiki maint 
 cleancache" www-data
2014-03-01 04:17:11,922 WARNING MoinMoin.log:139 using logging configuration read 
from built-in fallback in MoinMoin.log module!
2014-03-01 04:17:12,067 INFO MoinMoin.config.multiconfig:127 using wiki config: 
/opt/mydebianwiki/wikiconfig.pyc

root@tsunami:/opt/mydebianwiki# apachectl restart
root@tsunami:/opt/mydebianwiki# mv /etc/antimoin/ /etc/moin
```